# Eliminar espacio de fields null en reporte con JasperReport

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft

Estoy realizando un reporte con JasperReport, algunas columnas de mi tabla de MySQL tiene valores 'null', logro controlar este valor y que no se muestre asignando la propiedad `.blankWhenNull = true` en las propiedades del field.
Sin embargo, el espacio en blanco se mantiene, es decir, se oculta el campo que está vacío, pero el espacio del field sigue ahí, ¿Cómo podría hacer que ese espacio desaparezca y se recorran los fields que contienen datos?
Lo intenté con una propiedad de impresión; así:

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{field} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
```

Pero obtengo el mismo resultado que cuando uso .blankWhenNull. De igual forma asigné la propiedad isBlankWhenNull="true" sin tener éxito. Agradezco cualquier aportación.

Les muestro cómo lo imprime:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final, no encontré una solución para este problema, así que tuve que improvisar.
Lo que hice fue crear subreportes para subsanar ese espacio y así logró funcionar.